# how to generate a color histogram by concatenating the higher order two bits of each color component

Tags: matlab, colors, histogram

I want to use matlab to generate a color histogram. The standard way to do that is to concatenate the higher order two bits for each of the Red (R), Green (G) and Blue (B) values in the RGB space, which forms a 64-bin histogram. I am not quite clear about the concatenating process. How to achieve that??

I just got an idea but I am not sure it is right or not. Assume a color image A of uint8, my codes are as follows:

```
Ir = A(:,:,1);
Ig = A(:,:,2);
Ib = A(:,:,3);
```

Then I quantize each channel using 2 bits. After than the final pseudo color image B is obtained by simply concatenating the three quantized channels ( 2^6 = (2^2)*(2^2)*(2^2) ). The final 64-bin color image is obtained as follows:

```
h = hist(B, 0:63)
```

Comment: You don't have any ideas? Have you tried any code? Have you researched any ways of combining bits together?

Comment: I have check some textbooks. But I find they are not very clear about this point. I am not very familiar with color histogram generation

Comment: The histogram portion is trivial; you simply call `histogram()` on your data (possibly with the number of bins). But your question says you are not clear about the concatenation portion. What have you done toward that part of your problem?

Comment: For a gray-scale image, we can simply use histogram(), imhist() or hist() to generate a histogram with any bins to be specified. When it comes to a color image, it is a little different. It has three channels, which give three separate histograms. The question is to form a 1D histogram. Some textbooks say the standard way is that concatenation process to form a 64-bin histogram. I don't understand how that is done.

Comment: Are you able to take 2 bits of a `uint8` variable and place them in a specific location of another `uint8` variable?

Comment: can you be more clear about taking two bits? do you mean using bitget(data, 8) and bitt(data, 7) to obtain the last two bits?

Comment: Something like that, or `dec2bin` and taking slices of the results, or `bitshift`, or multiplying/dividing by powers of 2...